# Replace values between two data frames in R

Tags: r

I am trying to solve a little question related to two dataframes in R. I have two data frames `D1` and `D2`:

```
D1
   ID I1 I2 I3
1 001  1  2  9
2 002  3  5  9
3 003  8  7  9
D2
   ID I1 I2 I3
1 001 NA  1 NA
2 002  1  1 NA
3 003 NA NA  1
```

These dataframes are produced with the next code:

```
D1=data.frame(ID=c("001","002","003"),I1=c(1,3,8),I2=c(2,5,7),I3=c(9,9,9),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
D2=data.frame(ID=c("001","002","003"),I1=c(NA,1,NA),I2=c(1,1,NA),I3=c(NA,NA,1),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

The dataframe `D2` has rows with `NA` and non `NA` values. So I want to replace the non `NA` values in `D2` with their respective value in `D1`. For example in the first row of `D2` the second column in non `NA`, so this value should be replaced with `2` from `D2`. I tried building a matrix with the non `NA` values in `D2` by using this code:

```
mm=!is.na(D2[-1]) 
      I1    I2    I3
[1,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[2,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
[3,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

But when I trid to replace with a code like this `D1[mm]` I don't get the expected result. I would like to get something like this:

```
   ID I1 I2 I3
1 001 NA  2 NA
2 002  3  5 NA
3 003 NA NA  9
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
D2[!is.na(D2)] <- D1[!is.na(D2)]
D2
   ID   I1   I2   I3
1 001 <NA>    2 <NA>
2 002    3    5 <NA>
3 003 <NA> <NA>    9
```

Comment: Dear @DatamineR I am getting this error `Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, !is.na(D2), value = c("001", "002",  : 
  'value' is the wrong length`

Comment: Do you still get the error? I looked at the code of data.frame replacement function, which generates the error, but still cannot figure out why you get it...

Answer (score 0):

@DatamineR's solution is the first one I thought of as well, but it has the unfortunate effect of indexing the data.frames as vectors, which promotes the atomic type to character (due to the ID column), which you may not want.

Here's an alternative that preserves the numericness of the I1-3 columns:

```
aggregate(.~ID,rbind(D1,D2),function(a) if (is.na(a[2])) NA else a[1],na.action=na.pass);
##    ID I1 I2 I3
## 1 001 NA  2 NA
## 2 002  3  5 NA
## 3 003 NA NA  9
```

Comment: One can simply do `D2[-1][!is.na(D2[-1])] <- D1[-1][!is.na(D2[-1])]`

Comment: @DavidArenburg, dude, I think you've just provided the best solution. Make it an answer! I'd vote for it.

Comment: True, but it could be an important modification, depending on the use case.

Comment: I didn't know multiple indexing operations preserved lvalueness; that's good to know!